# NodeJS socket.IO disconnects when sending large Json

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io, large-data

I'm writing a multilayer card game (like hearthstone) with Nodejs back-end and  an angular front-end.

I tried to connect the two with Socket.IO, but it turned out that if I send a JSON object over about 8000char(the gameState object), then the client just keeps disconnecting and reconnecting.

If I only send the substring of 6000 char of the object everything is fine, but it crashes over 8000(I need about 20 000)

I have only tried in localhost

Here is the backend:

```
    constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.port = process.env.PORT || ChatServer.PORT;
    this.server = createServer(this.app);
    this.io = socketIo(this.server);
    this.gameService = new GameService();
    this.listen();
}

listen(): void {
    this.server.listen(this.port, () => {
        console.log('Running server on port %s', this.port);
    });

    this.io.on('connect', (socket: any) => {
        console.log('Connected client on port %s.', this.port);
        socket.on('message', (m: string) => {
            console.log('[server](message): %s', JSON.stringify(m));
            this.io.emit('message', JSON.stringify(this.gameService.getGameState()).substring(1, 6000));
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('Client disconnected');
        });
    });
}
```

Edit:It works perfectly well with ajax, but I would need sockets

Comment: Maybe try chunking as suggested in this [socket.io GitHub issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3135).

Comment: Yeah but my object is like 4-5 mb, not 300

Comment: When you send a substring are you actually just doing `gameStateJSON.slice(0, 6000)`? I'm wondering if you have invalid JSON somewhere after that 8000th character?

Comment: Normally I send the whole object, I just used the substring thing to test how much data I can send over the socket. If I send the object trough http, it works perfetly well on the front-end

Comment: It could be a timeout issue? You can adjust pingTimeout and pingInterval in socketio. You'll probably have to get more logging to know exactly what's going wrong

Comment: It disconnects and reconnects every 1 second, so I dont think the time is the issue.

Comment: @EzAz - Periodic reconnect can sometimes be caused by a mismatched client and server version of socket.io.  Are you 100% sure you exactly the same versions of socket.io on client and server?

Answer (score 6):

Socket.io has a default value of `1 MB` (v3 onwards) as the maximum data size that it can receive. For v2 and before, this value used to be `100 MB`.

You can use `maxHttpBufferSize` to increase the maximum size of data packet that you want to receive when creating the server.

```
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
    maxHttpBufferSize: 1e8    // 100 MB
});
```

According to the [migration docs](https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/#known-migration-issues):

> - the client is disconnected when sending a big payload (> 1MB)
>
> This is probably due to the fact that the default value of
> `maxHttpBufferSize` is now `1MB`. When receiving a packet that is larger
> than this, the server disconnects the client, in order to prevent
> malicious clients from overloading the server.
>
> You can adjust the value when creating the server: